# Unique set of random pair of numbers in Python

Tags: python, random, graph

I have an unknown graph where the number of vectors are `nv` and the number of arcs are `na`. I want to randomly determine `na` unique arcs using Python. I am struggling with the unique constraint on my problem.

I first attempted this without the unique constraint, which seemed to work:

```
np.random.randint(nv, size=(na,2))
```

If I have 3 vertices and want 5 arcs this could produce:

```
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 1]])
```

Which produces the arc `[2,1]` twice. I would therefore wish for my script to be able to identify that a arc is already been randomly chosen, and then chose a new unique random arc. However, I can't seem to determine whether this is possible using `randint`. Is there a different way that I should approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an array with the combinations and sample unique values with [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
S = 5

out = np.mgrid[0:N, 0:N].reshape(2, -1).T[np.random.choice(N**2, S, replace=False)]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

use permutations instead:

```
from itertools import permutations 
import random
na = 5 #5 arcs
nv = 3 #3 vertices 

#generate all the permutations of possible linked nodes in the form [i, j] 
perm = permutations([n for n in range(nv)], 2)

#randomly select na of them
random.sample(list(perm), na)
```

output

```
[(2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
```